# how to make get request url "api/reviews?start_date=mm-dd-yyyy&end_date=mm-dd-yyyy" in flask?

Tags: python, date, flask, restful-url, flask-restful

I am new to flask and I am building a restful api using flask .

```
class Review(Resource):
    def get(self, id = None):
        data = []
        if id:
            review_info = db.reviews.find_one({'_id': id})
            if review_info:
                return jsonify(review_info)
            else:
                return {"response": "no review found for {}".format(id)}
```

And My Routes Currently are

```
class Index(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return redirect(url_for("reviews"))

api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(Review, "/api/reviews/<int:id>", endpoint="id")
```

I want to create a get url "api/reviews?start_date=dd-mm-yyyy&end_date=dd-mm-yyyy" how can I do this? I don't want to create url of sort "api/start_date/../end_date/.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This you can achieve by using marshmellow lib which will give you facility to read the query params inside your get request .Below is sample implementation for your request

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
class ReviewRequestFormat(Schema):
     start_date=fields.Str(required=True)
     end_date=fields.Str(required=True)
     id=fields.Str(required=True)

class Review(Resource):
@use_kwargs(ReviewRequestFormat)
def get(self, **kwargs):
    id=kwargs.get('id')
    data = []
    if id:
        review_info = db.reviews.find_one({'_id': id})
        if review_info:
            return jsonify(review_info)
        else:
            return {"response": "no review found for {}".format(id)}
```

your routes will be like below

```
 class Index(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return redirect(url_for("reviews"))

api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(Review, "/api/reviews/", endpoint="id")
```

for more documentation on marshmallow you can refer -https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/